# カウントダウンアプリで動作の中断と再開を正しく動作させたい

Tags: swift, xcode

現在、カウントダウンアプリを作っております。

カウントダウン中にストップボタンを押して動作を止め、もう一度スタートボタンを押したら動作を再開したいのですが、私の書いたコードですと下の画像の様に見た目はストップしているのですが、スタートをボタンを押すとストップしたはずがしていないことになってしまいます。

どの様なコードに修正したら良いでしょうか。

---

[image: ２０ボタンを押す]

[image: startButtonを押す]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**19 : 45** のときにstopボタンを押します。

その**10秒後に**startボタンを押すします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

私の望む処理ではありません**19 : 44**から再スタートして欲しいのですがこのコードはstopした過去をなくしています。

**コード↓↓↓**

**画像を司るコード**

```swift
import UIKit

func secondsToTimerLabel(_ seconds : Int) -> String {
    let min = seconds / 60
    let sec = seconds % 60
    return String(format: "%02d : %02d", min, sec)
}

class NextViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var countdwonTimer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var executionTimer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var kyannseruButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var twentyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirtyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var sixtyButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ninetyButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        stopButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        kyannseruButton.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        twentyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
        thirtyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
        sixtyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5
        ninetyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5

        self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(TimerManager.shared.count)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        TimerManager.shared.onCountDidSet = { count in
            self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(Int(count))
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        TimerManager.shared.onCountDidSet = nil
    }

    @IBAction func stopButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if TimerManager.shared.isRunning {
            if TimerManager.shared.timer?.isValid == true{
                TimerManager.shared.stop()
                stopButton.setTitle("start", for: .normal)
                twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            } else {
                TimerManager.shared.restartCount()
                stopButton.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
                twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            }
        } else {
            TimerManager.shared.startCount()
            stopButton.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
            twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        TimerManager.shared.cancel()

        twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        TimerManager.shared.count = 0
        self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(0)

        stopButton.setTitle("start", for: .normal)
    }

    @IBAction func twentyButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(1200)
        TimerManager.shared.nowNumber = 20
    }

    @IBAction func thertyButtonActiojn(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(1800)
        TimerManager.shared.nowNumber = 30
    }

    @IBAction func sixtyButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(3600)
        TimerManager.shared.nowNumber = 60
    }

    @IBAction func ninetyButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.executionTimer.text = secondsToTimerLabel(5400)
        TimerManager.shared.nowNumber = 90
    }

}
```

**タイマーを司るコード**

```swift
import UIKit

class TimerManager {
    static let shared = TimerManager()

    let settingKey = "timer_value"
    let settingKeytwenty = "timer_twenty"
    let settingKeythirty = "timer_thirty"
    let settingKeysixty  = "timer_sixty"
    let settingKeyninety = "timer_ninety"

    var timer : Timer?
    var startDate : Date?
    var restartDate : Date?

    var count = 0 {
        didSet {
        onCountDidSet?(Double(count))
        }
    }

    var onCountDidSet : ((_ count : Double) -> Void)? = nil

    var nowNumber : Int = 0

    var restartBool : Bool = false

    init () {
        let settings = UserDefaults.standard
        settings.register(defaults: [settingKey : 216000])
        let settings20 = UserDefaults.standard
        settings20.register(defaults: [settingKeytwenty : 1200])
        let settings30 = UserDefaults.standard
        settings30.register(defaults: [settingKeythirty : 1800])
        let settings60 = UserDefaults.standard
        settings60.register(defaults: [settingKeysixty : 3600])
        let settings90 = UserDefaults.standard
        settings90.register(defaults: [settingKeyninety : 5400])
    }

    func restartCount() {
        restartDate = Date()
        switch nowNumber {

        case 20 :
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in self.twntytimer(timer)
            })
        case 30 :
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: {timer in self.thritytimer(timer)})
        case 60 :
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
                self.sixtytimer(timer)})
        case 90 :
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
                self.ninetytimer(timer)})
        default :
            print("Invalid value \(nowNumber)")
        }
    }

    func startCount() {
        startDate = Date()

        if timer == nil {

            switch nowNumber {
            case 20 :
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in self.twntytimer(timer)
                })
            case 30 :
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: {timer in self.thritytimer(timer)})
            case 60 :
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
                    self.sixtytimer(timer)})
            case 90 :
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { timer in
                    self.ninetytimer(timer)})
            default :
                print("Invalid value \(nowNumber)")
            }

        }
    }

    func stop() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func cancel() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }

    var isRunning : Bool {
        return timer != nil
    }

    func twntytimer(_ timer : Timer) {

        let now = Date()

        let sitting = UserDefaults.standard
        let timeValue = sitting.integer(forKey: settingKeytwenty)

        if restartBool != true {

            guard let startDate = startDate else {
                return
            }

            let dateDifference = now.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
            count = timeValue - Int(dateDifference)

        } else {

            guard let restartDate = restartDate else {
                return
            }
            let dateDifference = now.timeIntervalSince(restartDate)
            count = timeValue - Int(dateDifference)

        }

        if count <= 0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            count = 0
            self.timer = nil
        }

    }

    func thritytimer (_ timer : Timer) {  //途中ですtwntytimer(_:)が成功したら直します

        guard let startDate = startDate else {
            return
        }
        let now = Date()
        let dateDifference = now.timeIntervalSince(startDate)

        let sitting = UserDefaults.standard
        let timeValue = sitting.integer(forKey: settingKeythirty)

        count = timeValue - Int(dateDifference)

        if count <= 0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            count = 0
            self.timer = nil
        }

    }

    func sixtytimer(_ timer : Timer) {  //途中ですtwntytimer(_:)が成功したら直します

        guard let startDate = startDate else {
            return
        }
        let now = Date()
        let dateDifference = now.timeIntervalSince(startDate)

        let sitting = UserDefaults.standard
        let timeValue = sitting.integer(forKey: settingKeysixty)

        count = timeValue - Int(dateDifference)

        if count <= 0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            count = 0
            self.timer = nil
        }

    }

    func ninetytimer(_ timer : Timer) {  //途中ですtwntytimer(_:)が成功したら直します

        guard let startDate = startDate else {
            return
        }
        let now = Date()
        let dateDifference = now.timeIntervalSince(startDate)

        let sitting = UserDefaults.standard
        let timeValue = sitting.integer(forKey: settingKeyninety)

        count = timeValue - Int(dateDifference)

        if count <= 0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            count = 0
            self.timer = nil
        }

    }

}
```

また、このコードのどこがどうダメなのか教えていただけましたら幸いです。

---

**補足↓↓**

上記の処理を行いたいがために
`NextController`のstopButton部に下記の二つのコードを追加してみたのですがstop時からカウントダウンがうごかなくなってしまいました。なぜでしょうか

```swift
@IBAction func stopButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if TimerManager.shared.isRunning {

        if TimerManager.shared.timer?.isValid == true{

            TimerManager.shared.stop()
            stopButton.setTitle("start", for: .normal)
            twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        } else {

            TimerManager.shared.restartCount()
            TimerManager.shared.startDate = nil  //ここです！
            TimerManager.shared.restartDate = nil //ここです！
            stopButton.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
            twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }

    } else {

        TimerManager.shared.startCount()
        stopButton.setTitle("stop", for: .normal)
        twentyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        thirtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        sixtyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ninetyButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    }

}
```

Comment: クラス`TimerManager`の`static var shared = TimerManager()はstatic let shared = TimerManager()`の間違いではありませんか？どうも、質問者さんは、有識者から「シングルトンを使いなさい」と言われて、”シングルトンデザインパターン”の意味もよくわからずに、見よう見まねでコードをお書きになっている印象を受けます。ここはしっかりと、シングルトンというデザインパターン（設計様式）を、学習なさるべきでしょう。「Swift シングルトン」のようなキーワードでネット検索すれば、いくつか日本語の情報が得られます。（先ほど、コメントするつもりで、誤って回答として投稿してしまいました。謝罪とともに、投稿し直します。申し訳ありません）

Comment: どこからアクセスしても一つのインスタンスにするものという認識なのですが、ほかに付け加えるべき認識はありますか　[var → let 変更しました。]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***私の書いたコードですと見た目はストップしているのですが、スタートをボタンを押すとストップしたはずがしていないことになってしまいます。***

> **20 : 45** のときにstopボタンを押します。

(実際は**19 : 45**ですね。)

> その**10秒後に**startボタンを押すします。

(カウントダウンが始まると**19 : 35**あたりになっている。)

> 私の望む処理ではありません**10 : 44**から再スタートして欲しい

(これも「**19 : 44**から再スタート」ですよね。)

と言うわけで、うまくいかない例とはいえ、説明に誤りがあると、正解にたどり着くまでとんでもない遠回りになることもあるため、気をつけて下さい。

結論だけ言うと

**せっかく用意した`restartBool`を利用していない**

からだと言えます。

`restartBool`は`false`のままなので、`twntytimer(_:)`の中では常に「1200秒 - (`startTime`からの経過時間)」を`count`に入れています。リスタートの場合でも、リスタートした時(`restartTime`)からではなく、最初にスタートした時からの経過時間を使っているのですから、記載されたような動作になっちゃいますよね?

多分試行錯誤しながら現在のコードになったのでしょうが、`restartCount()`の中に`restartBool = true`のようなコードを入れても、所望の動作にはなりません。今のコードだと`restartBool`が`true`の場合には、

#### 1200秒 - (`restartTime`からの経過時間)

を`count`に入れちゃいますから、もう一度 **`20 : 00`** からカウントし直すような動作になっちゃうはずです。

---

こんな動作になってしまう原因としては、せっかくカウントダウンタイマーの「残り時間」を表す変数があるのに、それをうまく使えていない点にあります。

ついでに`twntytimer(_:)`から`ninetytimer(_:)`まで、中身がほとんど同じなのに少し動作を変えるだけで全部修正するなんて面倒だと思いませんか?

また、`UserDefaults`を`TimerManager`の中で参照しているのもいただけません。せっかく`NextViewController`からカウントダウンする「分」数を`nowNumber`(もうちょっといい名前をつけましょう)にセットしてもらうんだから、もう一度`UserDefaults`を参照する意味はあまりないですね。(`UserDefaults`を使うなら、`NextViewController`の中で使いましょう。)

と言うわけで、`TimerManager`に大ナタを振るってみると、こんな感じになります。

```
import UIKit

class TimerManager {
    static let shared = TimerManager() //<-有益なアドバイスはどんどん取り入れましょう

    var timer : Timer?
    var startDate : Date?

    var count = 0 {
        didSet {
            onCountDidSet?(Double(count))
        }
    }
    var onCountDidSet : ((_ count : Double) -> Void)? = nil

    var nowNumber : Int = 0

    var timeRemaining: Int = 0 //<- start/restartした時の残り時間

    init () {
        //`UserDefaults`は要らないんで`init()`も空っぽ
    }

    func restartCount() {
        startDate = Date()

        if let pausingTimer = timer, !pausingTimer.isValid { //`timer`がnilじゃないが、validでもない時だけrestartできる
            //現在の`count`を残り時間として使う
            timeRemaining = count

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
                self.timerFired(timer)
            }
        } else {
            print("Timer cannot restart") //黙って無視するとなぜrestart出来ないかがわかりにくいので、こんなのを出す
        }
    }

    func startCount() {
        startDate = Date()

        if timer == nil { //`timer`がnilの時だけstartできる
            //`nowNumber` * 60を残り時間として使う
            timeRemaining = nowNumber * 60

            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
                self.timerFired(timer)
            }
        } else {
            print("Timer cannot start") //黙って無視するとなぜstart出来ないかがわかりにくいので、こんなのを出す
        }
    }

    func stop() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        //`timer`がnilじゃないけど、validでもない時は「一時停止中」なんで気をつける
    }

    func cancel() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }


    var isRunning : Bool {
        return timer != nil
    }


    func timerFired(_ timer : Timer) {

        let now = Date()

        let timeValue = timeRemaining //<- 1200秒とかの規定の数ではなく、start/restart時にセットした残り時間を基準にする

        guard let startDate = startDate else { //<- このguardのせいで`self.startDate`が`nil`の時はタイマー動作は行われない
            return
        }
        let dateDifference = now.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
        count = timeValue - Int(dateDifference)
        if count <= 0 {
            self.timer?.invalidate()
            count = 0
            self.timer = nil
        }
    }
}
```

メソッド名など、ちょっとわかりにくいのもそのままにして、今のあなたの`TimerManager`と差し替えられるようにしたつもりです。ちょっと多めにコメントを入れましたので、動作を確認しながらお試しください。

(ちなみに **補足** に対する回答もコメント中にありますので、見てみて下さい。)

Comment: ありがとうございます！今後は説明に誤りが出ない様に確認してから投稿したいと思います。　わかりやすく丁重な回答、心から感謝申し上げます。　　毎度のこと目から鱗で、すごく洗練され簡潔にわかりやすい優秀なコードで感動しています。 あんなに長い不完全な動作のコードがここまで短く完全な動作のコードになるとは、、、驚きです。　大変失礼なことではございますがどの様に学びどの様に考えたらその様な秀逸なコードになるのかお聞きしたく思います。　これでタイマーの基本は出来上がりました、ほんとうにほんとうにありがとうございました！！！

Comment: @ahoahomarumaru さん、正直言って過分なお褒めの言葉のように思います。私の場合、初めてプログラミングをしてから早40年超(大げさに書いているのではなく、実年数です)のじじぃですんで、同じ方法論はあまり役に立たないかもしれません。(自分のアプリが書けるようになるまで40年待ちたくはないですよね?)と言うわけで、若い人にも役立ちそうなアドバイスを探すとしたら、コメント中にも書いた「有益なアドバイスはどんどん取り入れましょう」ですね、ただし **何が有益かどうかは自分の頭で判断しよう** と言うのを付け加えておきます。誰かがシングルトンなんてパターンを勧めたからシングルトンを採用したのではなく、今回の場合に有用な手法だと思ったからシングルトンを使ったわけです。(別質問になりますが)どこかに「こんな場合はデリゲートパターンを使え」と書いてあったから、デリゲートパターンを勧めたのではなく、自分で散々「多少面倒くさいデリゲートパターンの方が、いろいろな状況で逆に楽ができる」ことを痛い目にあって実感しているからお勧めしているわけです。短く言うと「感性を磨け」と言うことになるのでしょうか。現在は、ここスタック・オーバーフローのような優れたQ&Aサイトがあるわけですから、自身の感性を磨きながらサイトも有効に利用していけば、何十年もかけずにさまざまな技術をものにできると思います。

Comment: 私の思ったことに間違いはなかったのだと確信いたしました。私の年齢の丁度倍もの年月をプログラミングなされてきた御方にこうして御教授頂けているとは、、、私はとても幸運です。　感性を磨くことは難しい様に感じるのですがどの様にしたら磨かれるのでしょうか。本質問からはとても離れてしまう質問ばかり申し訳ありません。

Comment: @ahoahomarumaru さん、「有益なアドバイス」を得たり「サイトも有効に利用」したりするのも、大きく言うと他の開発者と繋がりを持つ、と言うことになるでしょうか。Q&Aサイトを利用する場合も「御教授頂」くなんて感覚ではなく、お互いに経験をシェアしていると言う意識を持たれると良いと思います。私自身他の回答者や質問者から学んでいることはたくさんありますし、あなた自身のご経験を公開の場にあげていただいたことで、他の方にも益するところがあるはずです。時間があるときには、特別質問することがなくてもQ&Aサイトをのぞいて見るのも良いかもしれません。

Comment: なるほど、、、わかりました！　行動面でも精神面でもその様にしていきたいと思います。度々ありがとうございます。